# Can I tell the "pip config" command to put the pip.config it generates in another location?

Tags: python, pip

I'm setting up pypi auth in some build and deployment automation.

It would be most useful to me if I could just programmatically generate a pip.config in the location of my choosing instead of having to write that file out manually or write it to the default location and then copy it somewhere else.

I'm using these commands to update the config:

```
pip config --user set global.index-url https://....myprivate repo
pip config --user set global.trusted-host myhost
```

Works as expected. I looked in docs and in `pip config --help`, but could not find a switch for changing the location.

Is there support to have `pip config` write the config file to another location?

Or is there some other command I could run first that tells pip the config is in another place and then when I run `pip config` commands it updates/creates a file there instead?

Comment: Do you want an *arbitrary* location, or do you want to switch `--user` to `--global` or `--site` instead?

Comment: I wanted to know if it could be arbitrary.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why would you need an arbitrary location? There's no `--config` option for `pip` to *read* from an arbitrary configuration file.

Comment: If you are trying to automate some common options for multiple virtual environments, I would suggest a shell script that runs a series of `pip config --site` commands, then run that after creating the virtual environment.